# Write permission to a file getting lost after file recreation in c++

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I have an MFC application which has 2 exes. They share a common resource file for reading and writing.Once the text file exceeds its size limit it gets recreated. After that only one of the exes is able to write to file. ie write permission is getting lost after recreation.

Below is the piece of code used for creating the new file.

```
CreateFile(FileName, GENERIC_ALL, FILE_ALL_ACCESS, NULL,
           OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Can you suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok. I will do that.

Comment: `FILE_ALL_ACCESS` is in the wrong place. You should explain in more detail what your goal is. You can try (just a suggestion) `CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)` this will create the file for writing-only, other programs can't access it. Then close the handle, open it with `GENERIC_READ` access. This is a simple approach and is less likely to go wrong. You can also use `CFile` in MFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is passing the wrong arguments to [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew), both for the *dwDesiredAccess* as well as *dwShareMode*. The former requests more access rights than needed. The latter is fatal, though, by requesting a share mode that conflicts with the access mode (it is using a symbolic constant that isn't intended to be used here).

To open a file for read/write access while granting other callers to access the file with the same rights, use the following code instead:

```
CreateFile(FileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
           OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

The MSDN entry on [Creating and Opening Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/creating-and-opening-files) lists compatible access and share modes.